# Дублирование адреса через htaccess

Tags: php, веб-программирование, .htaccess, веб-сервер

Предположим имеются ссылки такого вида:

```
site.ru/catalog/category/tovar-1/
site.ru/catalog/category2/tovar439/
site.ru/catalog/category313/
site.ru/
```

Как сделать чтобы данные ссылки открывались также еще и по такому url

```
    site.ru/dop/catalog/category/tovar-1/
    site.ru/dop/catalog/category2/tovar439/
    site.ru/dop/catalog/category313/
    site.ru/dop/
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^dop(/.*)$ /$1`

Comment: @splash58 не работает

Comment: кажется мне там надо в маске вынести слэш за скобки`^dop/(.*)`, а в замене `$1` его убрать

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть общий скрипт отвечающий за показ товаров, если его нет, то лучше его создать чтобы он отвечал за маршрутизацию. Маршруты в `.htaccess` можно сделать так:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule site.ru/(dop/)?(catalog/category(\d+)?/)?(tovar[\d-]+/)? site.ru/category?$1 [QSA]
```

К примеру контроллер `category` принимает в себя строку с параметрами `GET` и дальше уже подгружает соответствующий товар, иначе выдает ошибку.

Это один из вариантов решения, если вы используете паттерн `MVC`